# Paste "25 \%" in R for further processing in LaTeX

Tags: r, sweave

I want a character variable in R taking the value from, lets say "a", and adding " \%", to create a %-sign later in LaTeX.

Usually I'd do something like:

```
a <- 5
paste(a,"\%")
```

but this fails.

```
Error: '\%' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "\%"
```

Any ideas? A workaround would be to define another command giving the %-sign in LaTeX, but I'd prefer a solution within R.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As many other languages, certain characters in strings have a different meaning when they're escaped. One example for that is `\n`, which means newline instead of `n`. When you write `\%`, R tries to interpret `%` as a special character and fails doing so. You might want to try to escape the backslash, so that it is just a backslash:

```
paste(a, "\\%")
```

You can read on escape sequences [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Literal-constants).

Comment: That's because R is printing it as a string. Try writing it to stdout: `write("foo \\%", stdout())` and you'll see that there is only one backslash.

Comment: Please think about upvoting juba as well, his answer suits your problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can also look at the `latexTranslate` function from the `Hmisc` package, which will escape special characters from strings to make them LaTeX-compatible :

```
R> latexTranslate("You want to give me 100$ ? I agree 100% !")
[1] "You want to give me 100\\$ ? I agree 100\\% !"
```

Comment: @AriB.Friedman You're welcome ! There is a bunch of LaTeX related functions in `Hmisc`, it can be worth to check it out if you didn't already.